# Android gridView problems

Tags: android, gridview, adapter

First: `CustomGridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item>`

The Code:

```
ArrayList<Item> gridArray = new ArrayList<Item>();

gridArray.add(new Item(button, value[i]));
...
gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
customGridAdapter = new CustomGridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.gridview_item, gridArray);
gridView.setAdapter(customGridAdapter);

gridView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    // why this part doesnt work ?

    }
});
```

I have a gridView of buttons, why if i try to access them it doesnt work ?

Comment: Want to give us the error code, bud? Have you actually built the "CustomGridViewAdapter"? Is the context correct?

Comment: I created an ItemClickListener but still couldnt access the components :(

Answer (score 1):

You can't set an `View.onClickListener`on a `GridView`.
Instead set an `OnItemClickListener`

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //your code here    
  }
});
```